# UITextView created programmatically, allowing selection but no edit, ios6+

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, ios7, uitextview

I am trying to create a UITextView programmatically using below code:

```
- (void)setupTextView
{
    if (!_logDetailView) {
        CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;
        CGRect frame =CGRectMake(0.0f,2.0f , viewSize.width, viewSize.height);

        _logDetailView =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectIntegral(frame)];
        _logDetailView.backgroundColor=kEMCColor_Clear_Color;
        _logDetailView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
      //  _logDetailView.editable = YES; // tried setting this but didn't work
      //  _logDetailView.selectable = YES; // crashing on ios 6
        _logDetailView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _logDetailView.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

     //   _logDetailView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = YES; // tried setting this but didn't work

        [self.view addSubview:_logDetailView];
    }

    _logDetailView.attributedText = self.attributedDataString;

}
```

I am trying to achieve following thing:

> UITextView should be selectable but un-editable.

My problems are:

1. I tried to set selectable property as YES, but it crashed on iOS6.
2. I tried to set it as editable, but neither I was able to select the text, nor it showed any keyboard to edit it.
3. I tried to set allowsEditingTextAttributes as YES, but neither I was able to select the text, nor it showed any keyboard to edit it.

Comment: `.editable = NO` works for me. Or if you want the keyboard to show, set yourself as delegate and implement [`textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:) to `return NO`.

Comment: hey.. thanks for the reply.. I don't want it to be editable, but I want that user should be able to select text from it.. problem is - I am unable to do so using above code :-(

Comment: I tested both methods I said, both allowed the user to select but not change the text. If they aren't working for you, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: thanx.. got the mistake.. side-effect of categories ;)